# Flask/python route runs locally but crashes on GCP

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, subprocess

I am wondering why does the following Flask/Python route runs locally but gives an internal server error on GCP (Google Cloud Platform)?

Before including the route '/test/', I deployed to GCP and I was able to access all the routes.

After including the route '/test/, I was able to access all the routes expect '/test/' route which throws an internal server error.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

```
@app.route('/test/')
def test():
    p = subprocess.Popen(["coverage", "run", "--branch", "test.py"],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    output=err+out
    output = output.decode("utf-8")

    return render_template('test.html', output = "<br/>".join(output.split("\n")))
```

test.html

```
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
        <pre><code>{{ output }}</code></pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the error and traceback?

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "deployed to GCP"? That can mean several different things.

But regardless, there's a probably 75% chance that you just don't have `coverage` installed in whatever GCP environment it's running in.

Comment: Thank you, Mark, As you pointed out I forgot to include *coverage* in my requirements.txt file. After including it, the issue was resolved!

Answer (score 1):

`coverage` needs to be included in the requirements.txt file so it can be installed on the GCP Environment.